# How can a customer can be sure that the file came from me?

Tags: c#, security, authentication

Our company sends `files by email` to customers.

How can a customer be **SURE** that the file came from `my company`?

I was thinking about **calc** the **MD5** of the file and then send it to him with **another email**  (i.e. : "this is the second mail with the md5 for the first email file")

this will also ensure him (and us) if the the document has been altered

Is there any **smarter way**?

We don't have any web site that he can download files from ( certificate etc...)

We just send emails.

Comment: Consider asking in [security.se], they might have better alternatives. This isn't strictly a programming question. Just one point - your next question will be *"How can a customer be sure that the MD5 hash came from me?"* `:)`

Comment: You will need to encrypt the Hash using asymmetric cryptography, preferably using a certificate. No need for a separate mail.

Comment: you should consider provisioning some cloud storage space.  Windows Azure Blob storage gives you a globally accessible endpoints for distributing content.  The content can be public or secured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send PGP-signed e-mails.

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy

Answer (score 1):

Sending the MD5 in another email has the same inherent insecurity of the first method - how do you prove the the email originated from you? Unless you follow up with a phone call.

How about encrypting the file using [PGP](http://www.symantec.com/business/theme.jsp?themeid=pgp) or some other [Private/Public key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) encryption system. Then they can be assured that you were the one who sent the file.

Alternatively, try using a third-party website (like [Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/) or some similar service, that allows for you to upload files, and your clients to log in and access them.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this requirement typically comes along with a requirement for privacy - I would personally use some form of encryption to hide the file contents.  Send the customer the keys to decrypt the file via some other means of communication - such as courier, phone, or fax.

This, at least, eliminates e-mail as a single source of tampering.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no security expert, but I see a lot of security systems today using multiple means of communication to leverage security. think of for example banking systems using text messages together with their online banking tools. if you can employ a second means of communication for validation that would seem more reliable to me and in-line with most modern secure systems.